# Access button object in onclick function

Tags: javascript

```
<button onclick="play()" type="button">PLAY</button>
```

How do I access the button object in my play function so as to disable it?:

```
function play(){
    ???.disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```js
function play(element) {
  element.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="play(this)" type="button">PLAY</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the button object as argument inside the `onclick` attribute:

```
<button onclick="play(this)" type="button">PLAY</button>
```

and then retrieve it as parameter inside the `play` function:

```
function play(button) {
   // handles the event
}
```